# svnantlib.xml could not be found

Tags: ant, svnant

I have ant file like..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="antSVN" default="build" basedir=".">
<path id="path.svnant">
<pathelement location="svnant.jar"/>
<pathelement location="svnClientAdapter.jar"/>
<pathelement location="svnjavahl.jar"></pathelement> 
    <!-- <pathelement location="/home/ezdi/apache_ant/svnant-1.3.1/lib/svnant.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="/home/ezdi/apache_ant/svnant-1.3.1/lib/svnClientAdapter.jar"    />
    <pathelement location="/home/ezdi/apache_ant/svnant-1.3.1/lib/svnjavahl.jar" />  -->

</path>

<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpath="path.svnant"/>
<target name="checkout">
    <svn username="charvee" password="charvee123">
        <checkout url="svn+ssh://charvee@192.168.1.210/home/EZCAC/source/ezCACWeb" revision="HEAD" destpath="src" />
    </svn>
</target>
<target name="update-codebase">
    <svn username="${svn.username}" password="${svn.password}">
        <update revision="HEAD" recurse="true" dir="${project.code}" />
    </svn>
</target>
<target name="build" depends="checkout">
    <description>Main target</description>
</target>
```

it gives me error like:

Buildfile: /home/charvee/ANT_WS/antSVN/build.xml
  [typedef] Could not load definitions from resource org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml. It could not be found.
checkout:

what to do now??

Comment: In `<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpath="path.svnant"/>`, replace `classpath=` with `classpathref=`. Does that help?

Comment: nops it gives me error like 'undefined attribute classpathref in typedef'

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the following jars are in your `%ANT_HOME%\lib`:

1. `svnant.jar`
2. `svnClientAdapter.jar`
3. `svnjavahl.jar`

And then re-try. Hope that make sense.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question you answered is very old, so the original poster has probably solved their problem already. However, your answer might help someone else who has a similar problem in the future. Thanks for posting!